# React StepIconProps.classes do not appy

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to apply `StepIcon` styling as part of `Stepper` component, where eventually I would like to render the completed step icon color.

In my `StepLabel` component I am applying:

```
<StepLabel
    StepIconProps={{classes: {completed: classes.stepIcon}}}>{label}</StepLabel>
```

My classes:

```
export const MyStepper = withStyles(theme => ({
    stepIcon: {
        color: 'red',
    },
  }))(Stepper);
```

But when inspecting the classes with dev tools seems like the the **MuiTheme** class always overrides my custom override:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `red !important`?

Comment: I think it is a bug. In the [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/StepIcon/StepIcon.js) for StepIcon, the `root` component is the one providing default behaviour for completed by using `&$completed` instead of class.completed block. Root classes are applied first and I think that is a problem. `SvgIcon` does not do that, which I think is correct

Comment: @dubes Using `root` with `&$completed` did not help, do you mean I should use `SvgIcon` as `<StepIcon>` ? and how do I control the "completed" icon of the step?